# Открытие js из Python

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, веб-программирование, selenium-webdriver

я хочу сделать приложение что оно логинелось на сайте а потом жало на кнопку, проблема в том что кнопке в html выглядит так

`javascript:CCommentThread.DeleteComment( 'Profile_xxx', 'xxx'  ).`

Как мне это сделать ?

```
import steam.webauth as wa
import requests

user = wa.WebAuth('xxx', 'xxx')
session = user.login()
res = requests.get('steamcommunity.com/profiles/'+str(user.steam_id), cookies=session.cookies)
x = str(res.text)
n1 = x.find('commentthread_comment_actions')
n2 = x.find('img',n1)
print(x[n1+94:n2-4])
```

Comment: Добавьте код в ваш вопрос.

Comment: import steam.webauth as wa
import requests

user = wa.WebAuth('xxx', 'xxx')

session = user.login()

res = requests.get('https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/'+str(user.steam_id), cookies=session.cookies)
x=str(res.text)

n1=x.find('commentthread_comment_actions')
n2=x.find('img',n1)
print(x[n1+94:n2-4])

Comment: Вам нужна библиотека способная выполнять javascript, типа Selenium. С помощью `requests` вы желаемого добиться не сможете.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev , Я пока сделал с Selenium. Но мне очень не нравится то что открывается браузер. Так ищу другие способы.

Comment: @Arrow на сколько я помню селениум можно использовать в headless-режиме. Поищите в документации.